# Strike through blue colored rows after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

My code to strike through blue colored visible rows after filtering a table isn't working as expected

```
Public Sub EditRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Database As Worksheet

Set Database = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set rng = Database.AutoFilter.Range
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.count - 1, 1)
            
'Loop Through each visible row after filtering
For Each cell In rng.Columns(9).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
             
    'Strike through entire row if row is either these two shades of blue
    If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192) Or cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue Then
                    
     cell.Rows(rng).Font.Strikethrough = True
                
 End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Edit: Sorry for the confusion, the IF condition was based on the font color of that column instead of the interior color.

```
For Each cell In rng.Columns(9).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     
    If cell.Font.Color = vbBlue Then

    cell.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
 
 End If

Next cell
```

Comment: Hi Jon, please clarify the question. 'Isn't working as expected' - what's going wrong, and on which line of the code? (try stepping through using F8 to test it line-by-line)

Comment: Hi Spencer, I meant that my current code does doesn't strike through the blue colored visible rows like i wanted to. My code runs but nothing happens at all when i run the debug

Comment: Ok Jon, so does that mean that the code works correctly except for the line `cell.Rows.(rng).Font.Strikethough = True` ? Or is it that the If statement is never triggered?
If it's the strikethrough line, I'd suggest trying `Database.Rows(cell.Row).Font.Strikethrough = True`

Comment: You could put an debug.print "Test" in the if statement, so you see if its triggered or not.

Comment: @spencer I tried your code but it doesn't work for me. Yes, the problem is that i cant get the if statement to work and the debug wasn't triggered

Comment: @Jon Maybe it doesn´t trigger bc cell is defined as range and not as cell.

Comment: Are the colours done by Conditional Formatting by chance?

Comment: What does `rng.Address` evaluate to? Is it what you expect? Does it contain 9 columns?

Comment: @Simon Nope, it was manually colored

Comment: @Jon try looking up, what is the `Interior.Color` value on blue rows (either with watch window or by using `Debug.Print cell.Interior.Color`)

Comment: @braX $A$3:A$1522  which is all the rows in my table

Comment: @AntiDrondert its the default blue, RGB(0, 0 ,255)

Comment: Please, try selecting a 'blue' cell and try the next code `Debug.Print ActiveCell.interior.Color = vbBlue`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: @FaneDuru It returns False. Running another debug to check the color returns 16777215

Comment: So, instead of checking `If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192) Or cell.Interior.Color = vbBlue Then`, try using `If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 112, 192) Or cell.Interior.Color = 16777215 Then`. Now, what range do you need to `Strikethrough`? The next construction is strange: `cell.Rows(rng).Font.Strikethrough = True`... Do you want processing the checked cell, its row or what?

Comment: Be aware: 16777215  is vbWhite

Comment: @FunThomas: Meaning that he did not check the appropriate cell...

Comment: ...or the cell is formatted via conditional formatting.

Comment: @FunThomas: Not really. He stated "it was manually colored"...

Comment: He also stated that he selected a blue cell

Comment: Sorry for the mix-up, i confused font and interior. The IF condition was based on the font color. The code works now, but how do i proceed with this post? Do i accept the one answer?

Answer (score 0):

4 things:

**(1)** First thing you need to check is if your code is dealing with the correct range of data. Check if the variable `rng` contains the range you are expecting, eg by putting a statement `Debug.Print rng.address` after the assignment. If that is okay, check if the loop if using the cells you are expecting, for example by putting a `Debug.Print cell.addess` inside the loop.

**(2)** If you are sure the loop handles the cells you are interested in, check if the blue you are checking is the correct blue. Set a breakpoint to your if-statement, execute the loop until a cell is hit that is blue (check the address) and check the interior-color in the debugger. `vbBlue` is `16711680` (`&HFF0000`), your manually defined blue color is `12611584` (`&HC07000`). If the color matches, it should enter the `If`-statement.

**(3)** If the cells are blue because of conditional formatting, check `cell.DisplayFormat.Color` rather than `cell.Interior.Color`

**(4)** I assume that you want to strikethrough the cell having blue color, so the statement should be simply `cell.Font.Strikethrough = True`.